# How to write this extension method to be translatable by EF Core to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this extension method in my .NET code check if a string is something:

```
public static bool IsSomething(this string text)
{
   var isNothing = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text);
   return !isNothing;
}
```

However, I can't use it in my EF Core queries:

```
dbset.Where(i => i.Title.IsSomething()); // throws non-translatable error
```

I know that I can rewrite my query as:

```
dbset.Where(i => i.Title != null && i.Title.Trim() != ""); // this works, but it's too verbose
```

But I really don't want to write that long non-descriptive code.

How can I have `IsSomething` to be translatable for SQL Server?

Comment: Side note: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns true for null or an empty string, so that is all you need

Comment: If you want to introduce your own extension methods, you have to tell EF how to translate them. See [this article](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/custom-functions-using-imethodcalltranslator-in-2-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`; it does what `IsNullOrEmpty` does:

> Return `true` if the value parameter is null or Empty, or if value consists exclusively of white-space characters.
> *-- documentation for IsNullOrWhiteSpace*

And it is mapped by EF Core to an SQL of

```
@value IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(@value)) = N''
```

<sub>Note that in EF Core 6 this changed to `@value IS NULL OR value= N''` - same deal; SQLS ignores trailing whitespace in string comp</sub>

This means your `IsSomething` method is effectively `!IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, which EF will translate if you use it..

Answer (score -1):

You cannot translate this method to SQL Server. However, you can use a method that returns Expression. For example:

```
public static Expression<Func<Student, bool>> IsSomething()
{
    return (s) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.FirstName);
}
```

Usually, you should call AsEnumerable before using methods:

```
dbset.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Title.IsSomething());
```

But it will load all entities from data base.